# Unicode in powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, unicode, powershell-5.0

In my profile.ps1 I have this

```
write-host "→"
```

in the console it appears as

```
â†’
```

Though if I cut-n-paste the line into the console it looks like

```
> Write-Host →
> →
```

So there's obviously no problem with the font I'm using, and the command works, So what's going on?

Is it just that the character isn't being read as `→` when PS imports my profile? Does that have something to do with the text encoding of my profile file? I've tried this random command I found on the internets

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(850)
```

But it didn't work. I'm using VSCode to create my profile.ps1 file, and ConEmu as my console emulator.

Comment: I think VSCode has probably saved the PowerShell File (your Profile) with a wrong encoding. What does it say if you open it in VSCode, on the bottom right? I don't know if you need UTF8 or UTF8 with BOM. if it says something different, click on it and choose "Save with encoding" and select the correct encoding

Comment: @SimonS You should make this an answer, because it is the answer. UTF8 with BOM did the trick. Whatever UTF8 with BOM means.